# Merge downstream commits in GitHub (not waiting for a pull request)

Tags: git, github, fork, pull-request

One of my GitHub repos was forked, and the (downstream) developer made changes I'd like to merge immediately (it's one commit off my repo's current state). Said dev did not yet do a pull request. I was thinking there might be a way I could create a PR from the commit in his downstream fork.

- Yes, I could contact the forker to instigate a pull request (a kind of pull-request request),
- I could clone or even fork the fork, then spend time to apply the changes back into my repo

But I wonder if there is a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have, on your own computer (I'll call this "your laptop"), a clone of your GitHub repository, simply add *their* fork of your GitHub repo to your laptop Git:

```
git remote add xyzzy https://github.com/their/fork.git
```

where `xyzzy` is a terrible name for this downstream.  (Pick some better name, such as `downstream` or `fred`, and replace `xyzzy` in the subsequent commands.)

Now you can run:

```
git fetch xyzzy
```

You now have, in your laptop Git, `xyzzy/*` remote-tracking names corresponding to their—the downstream fork's—branch names.  You can merge any commits you like, and then `git push origin` as usual.

Comment: When I want to switch to the `xyzzy/master` branch to look at it (VSCode does `git checkout -q --track xyzzy/master`) there is `fatal: A branch named 'master' already exists.`. Not enough of a git guru to know how to proceed. Any hints you can offer in the answer to make it easy?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator: `git checkout --track xyzzy/whatever` tries to create a *new* (local) branch named `whatever`. In this case it's trying to create a new branch named `master`. You can't have two different branch names that are the same name: you'll have to call at least one of these branches by some other name. Pick the name you want for each local branch: one will be `master`, one will be something else. (Or both can be something else, as long as it's two different something-else-s.)

Comment: This has one bad side effect: at least one of your branches, let's call it `bob` for now, will have, as its upstream, either `origin/master` or `xyzzy/master`. That is, there will no longer be an obvious way to go from `bob` to "somebody else's `master`". One solution to this particular problem is: *don't bother creating a local branch name*. There's no need to use a *branch* name at all *unless* you intend to create new commits and need a good way to keep track of them.

Comment: The thing to realize here is that Git itself does not really care about *branch names*. What Git cares about are *commits*. Any name—such as a remote-tracking name like `origin/master` or `xyzzy/master`—suffices to find a commit by name. If you don't need to use a *branch* name, don't bother using one. Just use the remote-tracking name.

Comment: All that said, if you want to create your own branch `bob` with `xyzzy/master` as its upstream, use any of: `git branch --track bob xyzzy/master`, `git checkout --track -b bob xyzzy/master`, or lots of other harder to type in variants (but why bother when these two are easier to type in?).